# Find DAY with HIGHEST and LOWEST windspeeds using R, Python, or EXCEL

Tags: python, r, excel

I have an excel file with 31 tabs that corresponds to a day in the month of May. Each tab or sheet has 3 columns (Height, Spd, Dir).

I want to find the day that has the maximum wind speeds. I tried using excel's function `MAX=MAX(wind1:wind31!C1:C17)` to find it but it only gave a maximum value. Is there a way to determine the day that has the highest wind speeds of the entire month not just one max value, seeing as the height plays a role. Do I have to do some statistical juggling (pardon the lingo)?

I have the R software as well as Python but I am mostly a novice.

These are data from 3 of the 31 sheets.

```
        Day 1               Day 2               Day 3    and so on
Height  Dir Spd     Height  Dir Spd     Height  Dir Spd
139     333 6.5     110     254 3.6     157     341 6.9
790     343 5.9     767     264 4.3     814     357 6.2
1492    343 5.7     1471    274 6.6     1522    0   5.6
3079    297 9.4     3061    284 14.9    3127    317 10.3
4311    293 19      4291    289 21.9    4375    309 14.9
5731    291 28.6    5706    292 30.4    5809    306 19.1
7406    288 38.7    7381    294 42.8    7498    299 22.4
9462    286 47.6    9440    294 56      9550    290 22.5
10694   285 47.9    10679   293 61      10777   288 22.4
12129   281 46.9    12130   296 60.6    12207   292 23.8
13940   279 33.8    13936   296 40.4    13994   282 25.4
16473   279 13.8    16464   282 13.7    16517   286 11.7
18673   278 3       18665   324 2.9     18716   323 2.6
20786   63  2.3     20775   61  2.9     20824   59  4.1
24036   100 6       24015   104 4.4     24072   96  6.9
26676   85  5.5     26656   73  4       26719   83  7.9
31287   103 6.9     31253   102 7.9     31335   101 10.2
```

Comment: Hey "thelatemail" how did you make them look like a column? Thanks very much!

Comment: He formatted the text as code. This is accomplished either by indenting each line four spaces, or by selecting a range of lines and clicking the `{}` button above the text editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get your data into a contiguous format like this:

```
Day Height  Dir Spd
1   139    333  6.5
1   790    343  5.9
1   1492   343  5.7
.   .      .    .
.   .      .    .
.   .      .    .
2   110    254  3.6
2   767    264  4.3
.   .      .    .
.   .      .    .
31  26719   83  7.9
31  31335  101  10.2
```

You can simply use this formula in Excel `OFFSET(A1,MATCH(MAX(Spd),Spd,0),0)` where cell `A1` is the top left of the grid and contains the word `Day`. `Max(Spd)` is the max of the whole `Spd` column. `Offset` and `Match` are Excel functions.

Another solution would be to name the ranges of the `Spd` data in each sheet, say `Spd_1`, `Spd_2`,..so on, for each day. The Excel function `MAX(INDIRECT("Spd_1"))`, `MAX(INDIRECT("Spd_2"))`, etc,  could then be used on the named ranges represented as strings in a single sheet. You could then use a single `max` function to find the corresponding day.

If you can load the same data up in `R` as a data frame, then you can do something like this
`subset(df,Spd==max(df[,"Spd"]))$Day` where `df` is the name of the data frame you read in via `read.csv`, or `read.table`, or something similar.

Both of the above can be repeated the `min` in place of `max` to find the lowest speed.

If you can't get it into that format, or cannot use Excel's `INDIRECT`, then the best solution would be to use simple VBA in Excel to loop through the sheets.

In all cases you may have to think about how you will deal with ties - as in 2 or more different days with the same (maximum) speed.

Comment: +1 though the word Excel shouldn't be `formatted as code`, because it isn't code.

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with R making unique column names for repeated column names, you won't need to muck with getting the day # into the individual column names (that munging is a bit much for this post) and you can then just remove the "Day" header row, leaving month of columns of readings together like you have above and make that into a CSV that R can read with `read.csv()`.

This is the R data frame structure from reading in the data snippet above:

```
dat <- structure(list(Height = c(139L, 790L, 1492L, 3079L, 4311L, 5731L, 
        7406L, 9462L, 10694L, 12129L, 13940L, 16473L, 18673L, 20786L, 
        24036L, 26676L, 31287L), Dir = c(333L, 343L, 343L, 297L, 293L, 
        291L, 288L, 286L, 285L, 281L, 279L, 279L, 278L, 63L, 100L, 85L, 
        103L), Spd = c(6.5, 5.9, 5.7, 9.4, 19, 28.6, 38.7, 47.6, 47.9, 
        46.9, 33.8, 13.8, 3, 2.3, 6, 5.5, 6.9), Height.1 = c(110L, 767L, 
        1471L, 3061L, 4291L, 5706L, 7381L, 9440L, 10679L, 12130L, 13936L, 
        16464L, 18665L, 20775L, 24015L, 26656L, 31253L), Dir.1 = c(254L, 
        264L, 274L, 284L, 289L, 292L, 294L, 294L, 293L, 296L, 296L, 282L, 
        324L, 61L, 104L, 73L, 102L), Spd.1 = c(3.6, 4.3, 6.6, 14.9, 21.9, 
        30.4, 42.8, 56, 61, 60.6, 40.4, 13.7, 2.9, 2.9, 4.4, 4, 7.9), 
            Height.2 = c(157L, 814L, 1522L, 3127L, 4375L, 5809L, 7498L, 
            9550L, 10777L, 12207L, 13994L, 16517L, 18716L, 20824L, 24072L, 
            26719L, 31335L), Dir.2 = c(341L, 357L, 0L, 317L, 309L, 306L, 
            299L, 290L, 288L, 292L, 282L, 286L, 323L, 59L, 96L, 83L, 
            101L), Spd.2 = c(6.9, 6.2, 5.6, 10.3, 14.9, 19.1, 22.4, 22.5, 
            22.4, 23.8, 25.4, 11.7, 2.6, 4.1, 6.9, 7.9, 10.2)), .Names = c("Height", 
        "Dir", "Spd", "Height.1", "Dir.1", "Spd.1", "Height.2", "Dir.2", 
        "Spd.2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

and, here that is in a slightly better descriptive format:

```
str(dat)

## 'data.frame':    17 obs. of  9 variables:
##  $ Height  : int  139 790 1492 3079 4311 5731 7406 9462 10694 12129 ...
##  $ Dir     : int  333 343 343 297 293 291 288 286 285 281 ...
##  $ Spd     : num  6.5 5.9 5.7 9.4 19 28.6 38.7 47.6 47.9 46.9 ...
##  $ Height.1: int  110 767 1471 3061 4291 5706 7381 9440 10679 12130 ...
##  $ Dir.1   : int  254 264 274 284 289 292 294 294 293 296 ...
##  $ Spd.1   : num  3.6 4.3 6.6 14.9 21.9 30.4 42.8 56 61 60.6 ...
##  $ Height.2: int  157 814 1522 3127 4375 5809 7498 9550 10777 12207 ...
##  $ Dir.2   : int  341 357 0 317 309 306 299 290 288 292 ...
##  $ Spd.2   : num  6.9 6.2 5.6 10.3 14.9 19.1 22.4 22.5 22.4 23.8 ...
```

To get the column name of the max speed value for the whole data frame, we'll need to first just work on the "Spd" columns:

```
# only work with "Spd" columns

tmp <- dat[,which(grepl("Spd", names(dat)))]

# showing what we have left

str(tmp)

## 'data.frame':    17 obs. of  3 variables:
##  $ Spd  : num  6.5 5.9 5.7 9.4 19 28.6 38.7 47.6 47.9 46.9 ...
##  $ Spd.1: num  3.6 4.3 6.6 14.9 21.9 30.4 42.8 56 61 60.6 ...
##  $ Spd.2: num  6.9 6.2 5.6 10.3 14.9 19.1 22.4 22.5 22.4 23.8 ...
```

Then get the max value for each column:

```
# get max value in each "Spd" column
apply(tmp, 2, max)

##   Spd Spd.1 Spd.2 
##  47.9  61.0  25.4
```

But we really just want the column with the overall max value, so we'll feed that `apply` into `which.max`:

```
# which one of those has the max value (returns name & position)
which.max(apply(tmp, 2, max))

## Spd.1 
##     2
```

And are left with the column name/# with the max value.

All of that can be done on one horribly, unreadable line:

```
which.max(apply(dat[, which(grepl("Spd", names(dat)))], 2, max))
```

which I'm only including to show it's not as complex of an operation as the explanation might make it seem like it could be.

Answer (score 0):

Python and the pandas module is one possible solution:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python      
import pandas as pd

# Export the tabs as csv-files: day1.csv, day2.csv, ..., day31.csv.
# Assume the first line is a header line and that columns are
# separated by ',':
#
# Height ,  Dir , Spd
# 139    ,  333 , 6.5
# 790    ,  343 , 5.9
# ...
#

# Use or own column names and skip header.
column_names = ['height', 'direction',  'speed']

# Read in the data for each day.
alldays = []
for d in range(1, 32):
    fname = "day{}.csv".format(d)
    frame = pd.read_csv(fname, names=column_names, header=0)
    frame['day'] = d
    alldays.append(frame)

# Concatenate all days into DataFrame.
data = pd.concat(alldays, ignore_index=True)

# Get index for max and use it to retrieve the day and the speed.
idx_max = data.speed.idxmax()
max_row = data.ix[idx_max]
print("Maximum wind speed {} on day {}".format(max_row.speed, int(max_row.day)))

# Same as above but for the minimum.
idx_min = data.speed.idxmin()
min_row = data.ix[idx_min]
print("Minimum wind speed {} on day {}".format(min_row.speed, int(min_row.day)))
```

Save this as script `highlow.py`.  Using ipython and the example data provided I get the following:

```
>>> run highlow
Maximum wind speed 61.0 on day 2
Minimum wind speed 2.3 on day 1
>>> data.speed.describe()
count    51.000000
mean     18.209804
std      16.784853
min       2.300000
25%       5.800000
50%      10.300000
75%      24.600000
max      61.000000
dtype: float64
>>>
```